# Confluent CLI - Connect failed to start

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I downloaded Confluent-7.0.0 for local machine installed it. Tried to follow the Quick-start guide, I typed "confluent local services start" and got this error message "Error: Connect failed to start" Not sure what went wrong, it happens everytime even with old versions too.
I am using a ubuntu virtual machine.

```
Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.587467
Starting ZooKeeper
ZooKeeper is [UP]
Starting Kafka
Kafka is [UP]
Starting Schema Registry
Schema Registry is [UP]
Starting Kafka REST
Kafka REST is [UP]
Starting Connect
Error: Connect failed to start
```

When I run the kafka connect directly, it was able to start the service but there were a few error messages.

```
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource will be ignored. 
Nov 14, 2021 4:13:28 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConfluentV1MetadataResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConfluentV1MetadataResource will be ignored. 
Nov 14, 2021 4:13:28 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.LoggingResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.LoggingResource will be ignored. 
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Nov 14, 2021 4:13:31 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method listLoggers in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.LoggingResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains empty path annotation.

[2021-11-14 16:13:31,592] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@20a116a0{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:915)
[2021-11-14 16:13:31,608] INFO REST resources initialized; server is started and ready to handle requests (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:308)
[2021-11-14 16:13:31,608] INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:57)
```

Comment: 1) Your VM probably needs more memory 2) Show `confluent local logs connect`, please 3) Please run `connect-distributed.sh` directly so that you can actually see the errors

Comment: Hi, I will try to add more memory for the VM. 2) the log is empty if it fails to start 3) Running connect-distributed.sh  seems to have no issue at all

Comment: Hello, i have edited the question

Comment: There's no errors in what you posted. Few standard warnings, but things should work fine

Comment: I was following the Confluent kafka connector tutorial and the connector kept failing to start, there was no error message. In the web interface it just stated "Failed" as the connector status. And the data was not loaded into the topic that it intended to

Comment: heres the link to the tutorial: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-spooldir/current/connectors/csv_source_connector.html

Comment: Please show the actual error in the post itself, please

Comment: I created another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964861/failed-to-start-kafka-connector-spooldir-csv